# Angular 5 Form Submit, Wierd behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am having an issue with Angualar's submit:
My form looks like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="h-100">

        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form.value)" fxFlex="80" fxFlex.gt-sm="30" fxFlex.sm="60">

            <mat-card class="p-0 mat-elevation-z12 box">
                <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="bg-primary box-header">
                    <p>Portal</p>
                </div>
                <mat-card-content fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end center" class="box-content">
                    <mat-card fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="mat-elevation-z12 box-content-inner">
                        <span class="box-content-header">Member login</span>
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                            <input matInput placeholder="Username" id="login-username" [attr.disabled]="!loggedIn"
                                formControlName="username">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors?.required">Username is required</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                            <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password" id="login-password" [attr.disabled]="!loggedIn"
                                formControlName="password">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.required">Password is required</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field class="w-100" *ngIf="loggedIn">
                            <mat-select (change)="onChange($event)" placeholder="Select a role" id="login-role"
                                formControlName="role" required>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let role of rolesTemp" [value]="role">{{role}}</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </mat-card>
                    <div class="w-100" fxLayoutAlign="center center" *ngIf="!loggedIn; else isLoggedIn">
                        <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z12 box-button" type="submit" >Authenticate</button>
                    </div>

                    <ng-template #isLoggedIn>
                        <button [disabled]=loginDisabled mat-raised-button color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z12 box-button" type="submit">Log in</button>
                    </ng-template>

                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </form>
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

My submitForm method is this:

```
 public submitForm(values:Object):void {

    if (this.loggedIn && this.form.valid) {
    this.selectedRole = this.form.value.role;
    this.authService.setCurrentRole(this.selectedRole);
    this.loginWithRole(this.selectedUser+":"+this.selectedRole, this.form.value.password);
    }
     else if (this.form.valid) {
      let user = this.form.value.username;
      let pass = this.form.value.password;

      this.settings.loadingSpinner = true; 
      this.login(this.form.value.username, this.form.value.password);

       }
  }
```

The code behind it does the following:
I complete username/password and hit Authenticate. If the user has only one role, the login process moves on and logs the user in, otherwise, I come back to this page and show the roles in the dropdown, and then have the user select a role and then Log In.

My problem is the following: When I complete the username/password CLICK on the Authenticate Button, everything works fine, no errors what's so ever. But if i complete the inputs and then hit ENTER, I am getting an error:

```
LoginComponent.html:15 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

which I don't understand why it's happening. I have a breakpoint in my submitForm method but when I hit Enter in the form it doesn't stop my process, but when I hit the Authenticate/Log in Button it stops my application.

Any idea what might be causing this issue ?

Comment: Is this the template of your login component ?

Comment: Yes, this is the login.component.html.

Comment: You have no name property in it. Are you sure this is the code ?

Comment: Yup ... this is all of the code, I have not removed anything. That's the problem, is that I can't identify what that name is coming from and also, why it only happens when i hit ENTER and not when I click on the button.

Comment: Could you please post the code of the submit function ?

Comment: I updated the original post with the method.

Comment: No name reference there either ... Consider making a [mcve] reproducing the issue on https://stackblitz.io, since we can't seem to find any error in there ?

Comment: I will try but mostly the other part of the code is calling webservices. My main question/ issue is that I don't understand the difference of submitting the form with Enter ( while focus in on my last input ) and hitting the Authenticate button. Logically it should go in the same method not matter how i call it. Apparently with enter it skips breakpoints and everything else in there.

Comment: Agreed, hitting Enter simulates a click on a submit button. Maybe try having a single submit button and not two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for some unknown reason I have yet to identify, the error is happening because of the [attr.disabled]. I removed it and disabled from code those two fields and now it seems to work without errors.

I am assuming now there is an issue with how that gets interpreted and somewhere in angular core there is an error but that kinda beyond my comprehension.